# Tomato stems mysteriously cut above the fruit

Tags: plant-health, tomatoes, fruits

I have good healthy plants with no signs of (obvious) trouble. Fruits are forming, but some fruits on some plants, and there quite a few of them, are mysteriously cut. 
I don't see similar damage anywhere else on the plant(s).

[image: cut tomato stem]

(see exact place marked with white line on the picture).

Is it some pest? Bird? Disease? Lack of nutrients?
I'm first time gardener, so pardon my ignorance please.

Answer (score 4):

Something is snatching them off the vine IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the late answer but your tomato plant could have been cut off by a squirrel or rabbit, those sharp teeth nuisances. I am not sure if this relates to your problem but once I checked on my tomato plant and noticed it was wilting.  I thought it needed watering, but when I started watering I noticed my 18" tall plant had been sharply cut from the bottom (about 2 inches from the soil). I knew both those animals were pests in my back-yard. I started sprinkling chilli powder over the soil and it seems like the problem is gone.

Answer (score 2):

When I've seen this on my plants it's usually from me knocking a blossum or really small tomoato off the vine.  The vine still sort of grows along with the rest of the cluster even with nothing there.